# Closed form of a geometric series without some term

Tags: calculus, summation, closed-form, geometric-series

I have to study find the closing form of the following series:

\begin{equation}
f(1) + f(2) + f(3) + f(5) + f(6) + f(7) + \dots
\end{equation}

So basically the sum of all terms without the multiple of 4. Each term of the series is defined as: $f(i) = p^i$ with $0 < p < 1$ that is a constant. Rewriting the previous equation we obtain:

\begin{equation}
p^1 + p^2 + p^3 + p^5 + p^6 + p^7 + \dots
\end{equation}

So baiscally this is a geometric series without the multiple of 4.

My idea to handle this was to divide the series in 3 different subseries

\begin{equation}
p^1 + p^5 + p^9 + \dots + p^2 + p^6 + p^{10} + \dots + p^3 + p^7 + p^{11} + \dots
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}p^{4i - 3} + \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}p^{4i - 2} + \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}p^{4i - 1}
\end{equation}

In this way each of the subseries can be solved easily with a change of variable ($p^{4} = q)$.

My doubt is that since the series is an infinite series, this grouping cannot be done.

Is my solution correct? Or there is another way to handle this kind of series?

Comment: If all the terms are positive then you can group the terms however you want. The problems comes when you are dealing with a series that doesn,t converge absolutely.

Comment: A slightly simpler way of doing it is to write it as
$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty p^i-\sum_{j=1}^\infty p^{4j}=\frac{p}{1-p}-\frac{p^4}{1-p^4}\ ,
$$
but your method is also perfectly fine.

Comment: you can do grouping since the terms are positive and the series converges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that all the terms of the series are positive, rearranging (regrouping) them in any way us legitimate, so what you did is completely correct.

The only situation when rearranging terms of a series might change the value of the sum is when the series contains both positive numbers and negative numbers, and the sum of all the positive numbers is infinite and so is the sum of all the negative numbers.

Comment: Actually, the rearrangement used by the OP works in more general context. If $\Bbb N=A_1\cup A_2\cup \cdots\cup A_m$ is a disjoint union and all $\sum_{n\in A_k}a_n$ (with $n$ in ascending order!) converge, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\sum_{n\in A_1}a_n+\cdots+\sum_{n\in A_k}a_n$. Thus follows immediately from considering partial sums.